# What will happen if the number of units and the time-steps are different numbers in LSTM?

Tags: lstm

How will data feed the `LSTM` in following scenarios?
I have a data array with the shape of `(100,10,3)` and a `LSTM` like one of these:

> First scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 5 , input_shape(time-steps = 5, No_of_features = 3))`
>
> Second scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 15 , input_shape(time-steps = 5, No_of_features = 3))`
>
> Third scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 5 , input_shape(time-steps = 20, No_of_features = 3))`
>
> Fourth scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 15 , input_shape(time-steps = 20, No_of_features = 3))`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are sending the data into the LSTM. Lets say you have one data point with `t` timestamps. It can be of shape of `1xt` or `tx1`, which means you will be sending all the time inputs once into LSTM and while in the second case you will sending one timestamp of data `t` number of times to complete one data point.

Based on the number of `units`, the network computes what are the sizes `U`, `W` and `V` matrices. `units` just tells what should be the hidden dimensions the network should operate at. So it does not matter what is your input sequence length is. It is going to take in one input at a time and take the output of last input you put in and computes new output, when you unroll it and see.

**Edit**

> First scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 5 , input_shape(time-steps = 5, No_of_features = 3))`

If LSTM cell does not return the intermediate cell hidden states, it will output `1x5` output at the end else it will be giving out `5*5`

> Second scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 15 , input_shape(time-steps = 5, No_of_features = 3))`

If LSTM cell does not return the intermediate cell hidden states, it will output `1x15` output at the end else it will be giving out `5*15`

> Third scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 5 , input_shape(time-steps = 20, No_of_features = 3))`

If LSTM cell does not return the intermediate cell hidden states, it will output `1x5` output at the end else it will be giving out `20*5`

> Fourth scenario:
>
> `LSTM(units = 15 , input_shape(time-steps = 20, No_of_features = 3))`

If LSTM cell does not return the intermediate cell hidden states, it will output `1x15` output at the end else it will be giving out `20*15`

Comment: I edited my question to become more cleared

Comment: I added the answer for your edits .

Comment: Thanks Kirites, But I don't want to know output shapes, I wanted to know how will data go through LSTM cells when we change the number of units and time-steps?

Comment: Oh .... I will add that asap. :)